# Posting to Facebook friends wall instead of sending a notification with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I currently have the following code that chooses a random Facebook friend and posts to their wall. I would like to be able to choose from all friends (not select a random one) and post to their wall. If anyone could help me with the following code that would be great :)

```
 case gkAPIFriendsForDialogFeed:
            {
                NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey: @"data"];
                // Check that the user has friends
                if ([resultData count] > 0) {
                    // Pick a random friend to post the feed to
                    int randomNumber = arc4random() % [resultData count];
                    [self apiDialogFeedFriend: 
                     [[resultData objectAtIndex: randomNumber] objectForKey: @"id"]];
                } else {
                    [self showMessage:@"You do not have any friends to post to."];
                }
                break;
            }
```

this code selects all friends but doesn't post to their wall instead it sends them a notification:

```
case gkAPIGetAppUsersFriendsUsing:
        {
            NSMutableArray *friendsWithApp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
            // Many results
            if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                [friendsWithApp addObjectsFromArray:result];
            } else if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
                [friendsWithApp addObject: [result stringValue]];
            }

            if ([friendsWithApp count] > 0) {
                [self apiDialogRequestsSendToUsers:friendsWithApp];
            } else {
                [self showMessage:@"None of your friends are using Whatto."];
            }

            [friendsWithApp release];
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this function after get random id.

and change parameter according to your app.

-(void)sendFBPost:(UIButton *)tag

{

```
NSString *Message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-posted via iPhone App"];
NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                Message, @"message", nil];
NSString *post=[[appDelegate.FBFriendListArray objectAtIndex:tag.tag] objectForKey:@"id"];

[[appDelegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",post] andParams:params1 andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message!" message:@"Invitation Send Sucessfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

}

Comment: isn't there a way to change it so that instead of picking a random friend it shows all? thanks

Comment: What would I put in for tag.tag for the ObjectAtIndex? I need the user to be able to select a friend from a list of friends. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Posting to multiple users' walls is against Facebook Platforms Terms. You should stick with the Requests method instead, as that is the correct way to message multiple users.

Comment: I only need to select one friend and post to their wall. not many friends at once. Just select one from all friends and then post to their wall. The first part of the code does that, but it displays a random friend. I'd like to be able to select a friend from a list - like it does in the second block of code i posted above. thanks :)

Comment: In that case, you would need to build a view where you load the friend's list and let the user select which friend to publish to.

Comment: I already have that. the only problem is is that it's just sending a notification instead of a Wall post. That's all I need to figure out.